# multi language site map - valid xhtml

Tags: xml, seo, xhtml, sitemap

I tried to follow the instructions in https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en

and generated a large XML file. but the browser cannot display it as colored XML with option to colapse\expand its nodes.

I managed to simplify the XML file to this small version, which demonstrate the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset 
  xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/myfolder</loc>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/myfolder" />
  </url>

</urlset>
```

If I try to open my xml file using InternetExplorer - it does not displayed as "colored" xml, It only shows the text -"http://www.example.com/myfolder"

If I change the node name

```
<xhtml:link ...
```

into

```
<xhtml_link ...
```

The XML file does displayed colored.

Is there something wrong with "xhtml:link" decleration?
What is the correct decleration?

Edit1: add screenshots -
[image: un-colored - with xhtml:link]

[image: colored - with xhtml_link]

Comment: The link syntax looks fine to me. If I replace the colon with an underscore, all I get is a browser warning saying "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." Can you put up a screenshot that shows the "colored" xml file?

Comment: thanks, I added screenshots